# How to create ProgressDialog with pause and resume

Tags: android, audio, progressdialog, android-progressbar, evernote

I currently have url for an audio file. I'd like to create audio player like that in Evernote.[image: Evernote Audio player]

I have tried to create a `ProgressDialog` where the maximum value equals the player duration. But I have no idea how to add a pause/resume `Button` to work with both progress bar and audio. So basically this divided into three sub-questions:

1. How can I add a `Button` to `ProgressDialog`?
2. How to pause and resume the a) `ProgressDialog` and b) audio?
3. How to detect that the user tabs outside of the `ProgressDialog` in which case the audio should be stopped?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot user a pre-defined dialog for that. Create your own custom one. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) can you find everything you need to know about that.